# Execute a command at Emacs startup (emacs.el)

Tags: plugins, emacs

How to execute a command or a plugin at Emacs startup ?

I want to execute `shell-toggle-cd` (from http://user.it.uu.se/~mic/shell-toggle.el) at startup.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax for calling the function is

> (shell-toggle-cd)

You can put that in your .emacs so that it is executed at startup. Here I assume that you have loaded the shell-toggle.el from your load path in .emacs before that.

You can load the package by saving `shell-toggle.el` somewhere and adding this to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/somewhere")
(require 'shell-toggle)
```

Comment: Thanks but it splits my screen horizontally at startup :/ Is it possible to open the command on fullscreen ? Or to split vertically ? Thanks

Comment: you could run (delete-other-windows) after that

Answer (score 5):

if you just want a shell to open at startup, you just have to add

```
(shell)
```

at the end of your `.emacs`. This should open a new shell buffer filling up the whole window (unless you have some other command asking to get half of the window somewhere else in the .emacs).